Creating a custom column in power query assigning a crew number to a shift
I have multiple shift numbers in column titled "Close Responsibility" (originally titled "WOAPMUnit" in my source data set) that I would like to create a custom column assigning each to a shift (Day, Evening, Mid). The new Column will be called "Shift". The crews and assigned shifts are as follows:
Day = 22, 31, 35, 36, 41, 43, 45, 46, 54, 56, 60, 62, and 64.
Evening = 32, 38, 44, 55, and 65.
Mids = 34, 50, 52, 59, 66, and 69.
Inside this Close Responsibility column are also several lettered departments outside of our maintenance department (CTR, P&D, AATC, etc.) So I need to account for these as well and assign "None" for those.
Any ideas? I'm new to power query so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Share sample data as copiable markdown text along with your expected results.
